# Exception while running condition?

Tags: java, arrays, exception

There is no problem with the answer it is giving but with an exception.
Could someone help me understand why?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a = 0,k=0;
    Scanner obj = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("enter string");
    String s= obj.nextLine();
    int b[]={0};
    b= new int[10];
    char c[]= s.toCharArray();

    for(int i =0; i<s.length();i++){     
        if(c[i]=='a'|| c[i]=='i'|| c[i]=='o'||c[i]=='u'||c[i]=='e'){
            b[k]=i;
            k=k+1;
        }                       
    }
    for(int j=0;j<15;j++){
        if(b[j]!=0) {
            System.out.println("\n"+b[j]);       
        }
    }
}
```

The exception I am receiving is `ArrayOutofbound exception at" if(b[j]!=0)"`

Comment: What Exception and where? Please be more specific.

Comment: Please format your code and tell us where which exception happens including a stack trace.

Comment: Also, the code does not compile. `c` variable is not declared anywhere.

Comment: ArrayOutofbound exception at" if(b[j]!=0)"

Comment: why do you want ot initilize array in this manner int b[]={0};
    b= new int[10];

Comment: @Suganthan so how should i do it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is this `c[]` array here? This will cause compilation error if your code just as this. If it is fine.
You will get `ArrayIndexOutOfBound` exception here

```
   for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
    if (c[i] == 'a' || c[i] == 'i' || c[i] == 'o' || c[i] == 'u' || c[i] == 'e'){
            b[k] = i; // b[] size 10
            k = k + 1; // k can have value >9 
        }
    }
```

If that not happen following must give an Exception .

```
     for (int j = 0; j < 15; j++) {
        if (b[j] != 0)
            System.out.println("\n" + b[j]); // b[] is size 10 

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

b= new int[10]; 
b array size is declared as 10, but you are looping 15 elements(using j variable in below code).

```
for(int j=0;j<15;j++){
if(b[j]!=0)
System.out.println("\n"+b[j]); 
}
```

change for loop to 10 would solve your issue.

```
for(int j=0;j<10;j++){

}
```

There are lot of errors like c variable not defined.